# Babel will not compile .test.js files while running Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, babeljs, jestjs

While running yarn run jest --no-cache, An error is being thrown that says:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

My best guess is that babel is not reaching this this test file. Is their something special I need to include in .babelrc?

path:

```
/src/tests/LandingPage.test.js
```

test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactShallowRenderer from 'react-test-renderer/shallow';
import LandingPage from '../../components/LandingPage';

test('Should render LandingPage correctly', () => {
  const renderer = new ReactShallowRenderer();
  renderer.render(<LandingPage />);
  expect(renderer.getRenderOutput()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

.babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @hannad rehmann for the nudge in the right direction here is the solution that worked for me.

### Install babel-jest

```
yarn add babel-jest --dev
```

### Configure .babelrc for test env

Jest automatically sets your Env to test, so duplicate whatever config you want to the test env.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
        ],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Add `jest.config.json` to project root

```
{
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

### Finally, let your test script know where to find config file

I just added it to my test script in package.json, but you can also just run this in the command line.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json --watch"
},
```

Comment: i thought you already had babel-jest. and what you did is correct. jest has different ways of setting up. 
now the important thing to keep in mind is if you are testing something that depends on NODE_ENV. you might not get expected results because when you run jest it will change the environment as mentioned earlier .. cheers

Comment: where to find .babelrc file?

Comment: .babelrc should be in the root of your project if you are using a build tool such as Webpack. If you are using babel in the command line, this can be done using flags, but I would recommend a build tool to make your life a bit easier!

Comment: "Jest automatically sets your Env to test" - only if it is not set already. This can cause headaches, so use `env` command to verify if you have `NODE_ENV` already set to something else. In that case you need to either remove that or prepend your jest commands with appropriate override: `env NODE_ENV=test jest`.

Comment: I think no need to this step "Add jest.config.json to project root". Coz, according to jest documentation it is the default value.

Answer (score 3):

oh. this issue had me waste so many days. here is what you need to do. 
before that check these files.

1) `.babelrc` install corresponding modules and add them to package.json
define different env support as your jest always changes `NODE_ENV` to `"test"`

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      { "modules": false }],
    "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "react-hot-loader/babel",
      "transform-object-rest-spread",
      "transform-class-properties",
      "dynamic-import-webpack"
    ],
  "env":{
    "test":{
      "presets": [
        "env",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-object-rest-spread",
      "transform-class-properties",
      "dynamic-import-webpack"
    ]}
  }
}
```

2) add this to your `package.json`

```
 "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "automock": false,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dom/"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "lcov",
      "text"
    ]
     }
```

What I understood about this problem is that Jest will change your `NODE_ENV` to `"test"` and Babel doesn't have any configuration for this env, we normally define Babel config for development and production env. When there is no babel transpilation, `import` keyword actually becomes `undefined` as it actually doesn't exist in JS context.

Comment: Ok, the babel file makes sense to  me. I am a little confused on the package.json amendments.Where exactly do I add these in my package.json file? Also, are they all just jest configuration settings?

Comment: no this is just a Jest configuration that you should add to packages.json or jest config file @JordanHensley . ```jest``` will be written same as ```devDependencies```

Comment: I found a solution by installing babel-jest. Thanks for the point in the right direction!

Comment: “jest always changes `NODE_ENV` to `"test"`” - this is not true, only if it is not set already. This can cause headaches, so use `env` command to verify if you have `NODE_ENV` already set to something else. In that case you need to either remove that or prepend your jest commands with appropriate override: `env NODE_ENV=test jest`.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for solutions, in my case the problem turned out that I had my `NODE_ENV` environment variable configured to `development` for some reason.

Now **JEST only sets the `env` to `test` if `NODE_ENV` is not defined yet**, otherwise it'll use the value of `NODE_ENV`. This means if you have added in your `.babelrc` or `babel.config` file a dedicated part for the `test` (something like below), it will be ignored,and defaults (or the one matching your `NODE_ENV`) will be used instead!

```
{
...
  "env": {
    "test": { presets: [ "@babel/preset-env" ] }
  }
...
}
```

So if it looks like JEST does not transform your test files (which one of a sign can be a `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when running tests reated to your `test.js` or `spec.js` file) I'd recommend to check if you have `NODE_ENV` defined.
Use the `env` command (on MacOS and Linux or the appropriate command for your environment) to check the configured environment variables. If you have it already configured to something (other than `test`) you need to either remove that or prepend your jest commands with appropriate override: `env NODE_ENV=test jest`.

I hope it'll help others. Took me good few hours to figure out what was going on...

Comment: thank you , saved me a couple of hours for sure