# How to resolve "Cannot use import statement outside a module" from Jest when running tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest, ts-jest

I have a React application (not using Create React App) built using TypeScript, Jest, Webpack, and Babel. When trying to run `yarn jest`, I get the following error:

[image: jest error]

I have tried removing all packages and re-adding them.  It does not resolve this.  I have looked at similar questions and documentation and I am still not understanding something. I went so far as to follow another guide for setting up this environment from scratch and still received this issue with my code.

Dependencies include...

```
"dependencies": {
  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.6.2",
  "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
  "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
  "react-test-renderer": "^16.11.0",
  "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
  "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
  "@types/enzyme": "^3.9.2",
  "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.5",
  "@types/jest": "^24.0.13",
```

The component's import lines...

```
import * as React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./components/pages";
import {
  Footer,
  Header,
  Navigation,
} from "./components/shared";
```

The test file....

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import App from "../App";

it("Renders the Footer correctly", () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<App />)
    .toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I expected to be able to use named imports in my components without my tests blowing up.  It appears to fix the issue if I only use default imports throughout my solution, but I would prefer to not go that route.

Comment: FYI, I was running into this when setting up a custom TestSequencer for Jest and I just switched to using `require` instead of `import`, just for this one file.

Comment: This can happen due to issue with environment variables too. See my other, but related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63749183

Comment: In case anyone is running into this currently, this solution fixed this error in my case. https://github.com/react-hook-form/resolvers/issues/396#issuecomment-1114248072

Comment: @diemondtank its apparently a package (hookform) specific solution. I see `if (pkg.name === '@hookform/resolvers')` in the `resolver.js`.

Comment: This appears to be caused by a bug in Jest: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8365

Answer (score 289):

I was having the same failure (also using Babel, Typescript and Jest), it was driving me crazy for hours!

Ended up creating a new `babel.config.js` file specifically for the tests. I had a large `.babelrc` that wasn't getting picked up by jest no matter what I did to it. The main app still uses the `.babelrc` as this overrides `babel.config.js` files.

Steps I took:

Install `jest`, `ts-jest`, `babel-jest`, and `@babel/preset-env`:

```
npm i jest ts-jest babel-jest @babel/preset-env
```

Add `babel.config.js` (only used by jest)

```
module.exports = {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']}
```

In `jest.config.js` update to:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  }
};
```

`package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. Had to convert my .babelrc to a babel.config.js to do this but it all worked out!

Comment: for me, the new transform for typescript files was giving problem, solved by adding js transform to use the babel-jest i.e adding "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest" to transform in jest config js file

Comment: Works, don't forget to also install `@babel/preset-env` 

Comment: Thanks so much, this was causing me a lot of trouble too, your solution took seconds to include and like others have said - it works like charm.

Comment: This worked for me. Setting `preset: 'ts-jest'` in `jest.config.js` was key

Comment: i have this issue with a dependency of a dependency; had to add `transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!formidable)"]` in `jest.config.ts` on top of the steps above

Comment: thanks ! this worked for me too..... i dont understand how it fixes it though?.... any ideas ?

Comment: I don't believe this would work if you import `scss` files

Comment: Mine was missing the jsx option for babel-jest

Comment: This worked for me after hours of trying different options. big thumbs up

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH! This worked for me after finding the solution

Comment: great answer, ty. There's a quote mismatch in the module.exports example: `'^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest'`

Comment: Babel is already given with `ts-jest`. The comment above about `preset` is correct. https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/presets

Answer (score 98):

Use Babel to transpile those JS Modules and you'll be able to write your tests with es6.

### Install Babel/preset-env

`npm i -D @babel/preset-env`

### Create a babel configuration file with the preset

```
//babel.config.js
module.exports = {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']}
```

Comment: Direct and concise, thank you! For my project derived on [`tsdx`](https://github.com/formium/tsdx) this was the trick (along with `@babel/preset-react`).

Comment: `npm i -D @babel/preset-env` gave me an error.  Needed `npm i --save-dev @babel/preset-env`

Comment: This works perfectly! _(Just note that you *cannot* be using `"type": "module",` in your `package.json` if you go this route.)_

Comment: This worked almost perfectly. Had to use `babel.config.json` instead with ```{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}```

Comment: When `"type": "module"` filename extension should be **cjs** so name will look like this babel.config.cjs

Answer (score 36):

I solved this by migrating the `.babelrc` file to `babel.config.js`! Shocker.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, this fixed it for me. Not sure why the file needs to be js, but oh well

Comment: please explain more

Answer (score 35):

I fixed it by simply appending the pattern after the run statement in `package.json` runner

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns 'node_modules/(?!my-library-dir)/'"
    ...
```

Then, just run `npm test`

Comment: tnx. worked for me. but what does this command do really? is it kind of transform?

Comment: thanks this worked for me too, none of other answers worked only just by adding those commands worked

Answer (score 20):

For future references,

I solved the problem by using below jest config, after reading Logan Shoemaker's answer.

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>src/setupTests.ts"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/file.js",
  }
};
```

Comment: My Jest config was only missing **moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],** of which I added and everything start working as expected. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, `moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx" ]` fixed it in my case

Answer (score 14):

try this thing if you are using babel 6

1. Adding `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` in the plugin section of `babel.config.js`

or

2. For my case import issue was due to the react file drop by adding that to `transformIgnorePatterns`

`"transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!react-file-drop)"]`

Comment: In my case, helped only `transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!react-hls-player)'],`

Comment: Wow, step 1 solved the problem for me, using Babel 7. Amazing. So many possible solutions here, but this was the one that did it for me.

Comment: Option 1 fixed it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Solution: my named imports were coming from index.js files and I believe ts-jest needed them as index.ts files (I'm using Typescript).  If anyone else runs into this error, couldn't hurt to check if you derped your file extensions.

I wasted a lot of time on this, unfortunately, but I learned a lot about webpack configurations and Babel.

Comment: How did you solve the problem with the `index.js` in other modules?

Comment: I spend two hours resolving this error. And well, after reading this answer, I want to cry right now T_T. I'm migrating from js to typescript and I forgot to rename ".js" to ".ts"

Comment: Why must the imports come from `index.ts` only? I have plenty of TS files from where I directly do `export class ABC` and I'd expect it to work. :-(

Comment: Also curious to know how did you sort this specific issue in the end.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised that none of the answers does not give an elegant solution:

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
  },
};
```

This compiles each file separately therefore avoiding the no exports issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also suprised that nobody upvote your answer soon, but you solved my problem !

Comment: not so elegant for me...doesn't work

Comment: I tried this but get "(WARN) Define `ts-jest` config under `globals` is deprecated." and it also didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Add your `test` script in `package.json` with Node experimental feature: `--experimental-vm-modules`

In this way you won't require babel or other dependencies.

Examples:

```sh
"test": "NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules --experimental-specifier-resolution=node' jest"
```

If you get this error: `zsh: command not found: jest`, try with `node` passing `jest.js` like this:

```sh
"test": "NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --trace-warnings' node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --detectOpenHandles"
```

Comment: For me, the following: ` "test": "NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules --experimental-specifier-resolution=node' jest",` doesn't fix the error, but instead changes it from `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` to `Must use import to load ES Module: `

Comment: Add `--experimental-modules` in your flags

Answer (score 4):

I discovered that this error might be triggered when you try to load a dependency that is made for the browser and, thus, cannot work with jest (node).

I had a lot of trouble solving this issue for `@zip.js/zip.js` lib. But I could do it like that:

Here is my `jest.config.js`. Adapt it to your need. The trick here is the moduleNameMapper that will make all imports to zip.js point to the file `__mocks__/@zip.js/zip.js` I created in my root folder.

```js
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@zip.js/zip.js': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/@zip.js/zip.js',
  },
}
```

And here is what I have in `<rootDir>/__mocks__/@zip.js/zip.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {}
```

Comment: In my case, it was exacly this problem regarding AXIOS. Fixed it with transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!axios)/\"

Answer (score 2):

Create `.babelrc` on the main directory and add this code and install these packages
@babel/core, @babel/preset-env and @babel/preset-react

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": "commonjs"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Adding `"modulejs": "commonjs"` did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do a couple things to get this to work for me

1. Rename my `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` and make a little change:

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "corejs": "3.26",
        "useBuiltIns": "usage"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  ...
}
```

```
// babel.config.js - This still works fine with webpack
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "corejs": "3.26",
        "useBuiltIns": "usage"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  ...
}
```

2. Add the following to my **jest** config file:

```
{
  ...  
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(react-leaflet-custom-control)/)"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Where `react-leaflet-custom-control` was the package causing issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

Matching file extensions:

I importing a file named `Todo.jsx` in the root as `./src/Todo/`. Whenever I changed it to `Todo.js` the problem went away.

Disclaimer: I'm not sure what the requirement is for having your file extension as `jsx` vs `js` for your components. It did not effect me at all, but I could imagine it could mess with intellisense or snippets.

Answer (score 1):

For me renaming file to `babel.config.js` worked.
Here is my config file an NX project using next with Typescript along with Twin-macro

```js
// .babelrc.js >> babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@nrwl/react/babel",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic",
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [">0.25%", "not dead"]
        },
        "preset-react": {
          runtime: "automatic",
          importSource: "@emotion/react",
        },
      }
    ],
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop',
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ],
  plugins: ['@emotion', 'macros', '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', 'react-docgen'],
}
```

Also, please note even updating `package.json` works,
https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/presets/#basic-usage

```
// package.json
"jest": {
    // Replace `ts-jest` with the preset you want to use
    // from the above list
    "preset": "ts-jest"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version. Imports work with jest `29.5.0` and ts-jest `29.1.0`

`yarn upgrade jest ts-jest`

jest.config.json

```
  "roots": ["<rootDir>/"],
  "collectCoverageFrom": ["src/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.ts?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testMatch": ["<rootDir>/**/?(*.)(spec|test).(ts|js)?(x)"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with Typescript, Jest, and VueJS/VueCli 3. The normal build has no problem. only happens for Jest. I struggled for hours by searching. But no answer actually works. In my case, I have a dependency on my own typescript package which I specific **"target": "es6"** in the **tsconfig.json**. That's the root cause. So the solution is simply to change the **dependent**'s (Not the same project) back to **es5** tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in my original post. I was using **es6** in the dependent module. That's the root cause of the problem. After I changed back to **es5**, the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I followed @ajwl setup but discovered that `jsdom-worker` inside `setupFiles:` section of `jest.config.js` was triggering that same error. Once removed, my tests were passing.

P.S. my `babel.config.js` is a bit different, since I have a Vuejs (v2) SPA (bundled with Vitejs):

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that jest doesn't support esmodules natively. Which can cause problems if youre typescript target is es6 or greater.

If you are testing the built typescript output, you could simply add a `module=commonjs` flag while transpiling. That way, your code can run with es6 or greater and still work with Jest.

```
"scripts": {
  "test": tsc --module commonjs && jest {your-output-folder}/
}
```

What's great about this is that I didn't have to add any additional babel dependencies or special jest runners :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing my `tsconfig.json` to a compatible native output

```
"module": "commonjs", /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
```

It is not ideal in every scenario but you might be okay with this.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do, was **simply** updating the package `@babel/preset-env` in the **dev dependencies** to the **latest version**

```
// package.json
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6"
```

Comment: Nope, this didn't help for me

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped me, what did help me was making sure my NODE_ENV was set to test, since babel config is per NODE_ENV using the wrong NODE_ENV by accident that is not configured in babel config will mean you wont be using babel and the typescript files will not be transformed.

It took me couple of hours to figure this one out so i hope it will save someone else the time it took me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why and how but how I solved the problem was really interesting.
Just add `__mocks__` folder in your src folder and create an empty file inside `__mocks__` named `axios.js`

Comment: [manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with Next.js version 13. This github ticket lead me to the correct approach https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/36077#issuecomment-1096635363

```js
module.exports = async () => ({
    ...await createJestConfig(customJestConfig)(),
    // An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        'node_modules/(?!(query-string|decode-uri-component|split-on-first|filter-obj|crypto-es|strict-uri-encode)/)',
        '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
    ]
});
```

In my case query-string was the problem package, which also required the other packages to be ignored as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `transformIgnorePatterns` option.

If you want to transform NPM modules, you can use `transformIgnorePatterns` option and add your module name to its value REG EXP.

Attention! The module name you use must be **full module name**.

For example, if you want `react-native` to be transformed, you must use its full name: `react-native`. Part of name, like `native` is **NOT** work.

```js
  // jest.config.js
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(react-native|must-be-full-module-name)/)"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use `ts-jest` to process your `*.js` ESM.

1. exclude your lib of `transformIgnorePatterns`

   ```
   "transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!(@mylib)/)"]
   ```
2. transform your lib with `ts-jest`

   ```
   "transform": {
       "(\\.ts$|@mylib)":  ["ts-jest", {}]
   }
   ```
3. tell typscript to `allowJs`

   ```
   "compilerOptions": {
       "allowJs": true
   }
   ```

**No extra dependencies needed.**

Here's a sample of my config to test with browserfs:

```
// jest.config.json
{
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/(?!(@browserfs)/)"],
    "transform": {"(\\.ts$|@browserfs)": ["ts-jest", {
        "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/tests/tsconfig.json",
        "useESM": true
    }]}
}

// tests/tsconfig.json
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) I had to change the `transformIgnorePatterns` to the correct path `node_modules/.pnpm`:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/.pnpm/(?!package-name)']
```

Answer (score -2):

Too late for this answer :)
After trying all the possible solutions, this worked for me:
The solution, that works for me:

> 1. create a file named jest/mocks/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics.js
>
> > `export default () => ({ log: jest.fn(), recordError: jest.fn(), });`

> 2. create a file named jest/jestSetupFile.js
>
> > `import mockFirebaseCrashlytics from './mocks/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';`

> > `jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/crashlytics', () => mockFirebaseCrashlytics);`

> 3. in package.json add
>
> > `"jest": { "setupFiles": ["./jest/jestSetupFile.js"] },`

Comment: There is no mention of Firebase or react native in the original post. The answer does not make sense

Answer (score -5):

Rename your test file from '.js' to '.ts'

Comment: Hey, this worked for me! Have an upvote! I'm using `ts-jest` so I'm assuming that it doesn't process js files

Comment: Not necessary if you add `moduleFileExtensions` to Jest config or enable the new `allowImportingTsExtensions` setting in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score -7):

If you're using TypeScript, and you have a tsconfig.json file, try removing `"module": "esnext"` if you're using it

[image]

Answer (score -16):

Running `npm ci` fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Please provide evidence if you believe this is the fix for you.