# Jest return error when using "import * as .."

Tags: jestjs, next.js, babel-jest

I have problems to run my test suite when I used `import * as './filename.js'` with Jest.
All the others imports run without problems so I don't think is a problem with babel configuration.
I use Nextjs 10(so react17), Jest, Typescript and babel-jest.

Here is my babel.config.js

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": ["next/babel"]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "next/babel",
          {
            "preset-env": {
              "modules": "commonjs"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And here an example of the test that gives the error:

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Header from '../Header/Header'
import HeaderHome from '../HeaderHome/HeaderHome'
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer'
import styles from './Layout.module.css'

import * as settingsHelper from '../../helpers/_settingsHelper'

// .... normal react component here.
```

And inside the `_seetingsHelper.js` I call my cookieHelper like so:

```
import * as cookieHelper from './_cookies'

function initialise () {
 // body of function here
}
```

error:

```
.../helpers/_settingsHelper.js:2
    import * as cookieHelper from './_cookies'
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

       6 | import styles from './Layout.module.css'
       7 |
    >  8 | import * as settingsHelper from '../../helpers/_settingsHelper'
         | ^
       9 |
      10 | // prettier-ignore
      11 | interface LayoutProps {
```

Someone already encountered this issue?

Comment: There are a lot of people who have encountered similar kind of issue with the same error as that you have mentioned above. You can check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest. There is no generic solution for this problem. Mostly the root cause for the error is project specific.

Comment: hey thanks! I was finding just documentation and others solution about how to install babel-jest or ts-jest. But this answer you linked me go a bit deeper in the problem. Some of their solution might be useful for me, the problematic component is indeed a .js file, the only one. 
Thanks @TejaGoudKandula

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers.