# Testing Node with Jest Error: Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

I am testing my backend with Jest, but keep getting this error. Am I missing something in my Jest configuration?

```
"jest": {
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/",
            "package.json",
            "package-lock.json"
        ],
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "routes/**/*.{js,jsx}",
            "middleware/**/*.{js,jsx}",
            "models/**/*.{js,jsx}",
            "utils/**/*.{js,jsx}"
        ],
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "transform": {
            "\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error

```
{import { app } from './server.js';
 ^^^^^^
```

This is what I am testing:

```
import { app } from './server.js'

describe("PUT ", function () {
it("Respond with 200", function (done) {

    request(app)
        .put('/:id/pay')
        .send("{}")
        .expect(200)
        .end(function (err, res) {
            done();
        })

});

})
```

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error? and how are you exporting `app`?

Comment: I updated the post with a picture of the error I get on powershell

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest

Comment: I came across that post a few hours ago and I kept getting the same error. Tried it again right now and it works. Very confusing...

Comment: https://pics.me.me/it-doesnt-work-why-it-works-why-2349750.png

Comment: How I've been feeling this entire school semester