# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module in test files

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, create-react-app, react-testing-library

I used **create-react-app** for creating a react app,later built components for my use case.The components I built uses **internal company libraries**.I started writing tests.I wrote a simple test which will just render the component. Components which does not use internal libraries are working fine when I imported them in a test file and rendered, but the components which use internal libraries are throwing this error **SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module** pointing to the import statement of internal library used in the component.Can someone help me in solving this issue. Note: I am new to react and used **create-react-app**.This the code in test file

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Detailpage from '../Detailpage';

test('renders detailpage', () => {
  render(<Detailpage />);
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest)