# unable to run tests using react-testing-library "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

here is a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9kvg). the issue can be triggered by typing `npm run test -- -t "Store"` into the console. The error that will be returned is `Cannot use import statement outside a module` because when compiled `import React from "react";` is being added to `util\store.test.tsx` for reasons I don't understand.

The error is only encountered when using imports (and jsx) from `react-testing-library`

I have tried every suggestion listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest) and nothing works.

my `jest.config.ts` is;

```
export default {
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  coverageProvider: "v8"
}
```

and `babel.config.js` is;

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      'next/babel',
      ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
      '@babel/preset-typescript'
    ]
  };
```

I believe this is a somewhat unique error given interactions of specific libaries used in my project which is why other suggestions have not be able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for reasons unknown there seemed to be a problem with my `babel.config.js` file (not provided in the original questions, sorry)

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
      'next/babel',
      ['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
      '@babel/preset-typescript'
    ]
  };
```

This was originally put in place to make `Typescript` work in `Next.js` but wasn't needed and was breaking `Jest`. Deleting the file worked, however, i have since set it to;

```
module.exports = {
    "presets": [
        "next/babel"
    ],
    "plugins": []
}
```

It was a problem with `preset-env` as deleting that line specifically fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change [JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) mode to `"jsx": "react"` for `tsconfig.json`.
2. Add [ts-jest](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/) package
3. Modify the `jest.config.ts` like this:

```
export default {
  preset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  clearMocks: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",
  coverageProvider: "v8"
}
```

4. `npm run test -- -t "Store"`

Test result:

```
sandbox@sse-sandbox-91opf:/sandbox$ npm run test -- -t "Store"

> music-quiz@0.1.0 test /sandbox
> jest "-t" "Store"

 FAIL  util/store.test.tsx (32.906 s)
  ● Store: › Should work

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "h1"

    Here are the accessible roles:

      heading:

      Name "":
      <h1 />

      --------------------------------------------------

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body>
      <div>
        <h1 />
      </div>
    </body>

       6 |   it("Should work", () => {
       7 |     render(<h1></h1>);
    >  8 |     expect(screen.getAllByRole("h1")).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                   ^
       9 |   });
      10 |   it("definitely work", () => {
      11 |     expect(true).toBe(true);

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:38:19)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:90:38
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:130:15
      at Object.<anonymous> (util/store.test.tsx:8:19)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------------------------
All files |   36.17 |      100 |       0 |   36.17 |
 maths.ts |   11.11 |      100 |       0 |   11.11 | 1-5,7-9
 notes.ts |   37.87 |      100 |       0 |   37.87 | ...46,63-94,98-111,113-116,118-132
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|------------------------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 skipped, 1 of 3 total
Tests:       1 failed, 30 skipped, 1 passed, 32 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        37.472 s, estimated 49 s
Ran all test suites with tests matching "Store".
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! music-quiz@0.1.0 test: `jest "-t" "Store"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the music-quiz@0.1.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sandbox/.npm/_logs/2021-11-25T04_42_32_701Z-debug.log
```

Test environment setup correctly, but your test case failed.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-beaver-91opf?file=/jest.config.ts:4744-4768)

Comment: You forgot to mention that i need to manually include React into every file. This is fantastic. Could you explain why this worked?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work, `Next.js` doesn't allow you to use `"jsx": "react"`