# JEST for Javascript unable to convert import/export and giving error Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babel-jest

I am writing integration tests for **Javascript** code using **Jest**. But I am seeing **SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module**. Its been quiet sometime I have been on this and this issue is killing my time! I have all the configuration in place but still this isn't working. Also followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71058618/to-have-some-of-your-node-modules-files-transformed-you-can-specify-a-custom) but in vain.

**Error Details:**

```
C:xx\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js:9
import http from 'node:http';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

And when I checked **index.js** of **node-fetch** it has has import statements.

**Project Structure:**

```
-resources
   |__package.json
   |__babel.config.js
   |__node_modules
   |__static
          |__integration-tests
                     |__somescript.int.test.js
```

**babel.config.js:**

```
module.exports ={
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
    plugins: [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
    ]
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "some-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --testRegex='script/integration-tests/.*(int-test))\\.js?$'"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.3",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.10",
    "uglify-js": "3.16.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.0",
    "@babel/cli":^7.18.10,
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.0.2"
  }
}
```

**validator.js(Javascript):**

```
import {fetch} from 'node-fetch';

function validate(){
    fetch(SOME_UENDPOINT_URL, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers:{
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response;
    }).then(data => {
        
    });     
}
```

**validator-int.test.js(Jest script)**

```
const{validate} = require('../scripts/validator');

describe('User validation', () => {
     test('Should authenticate user', ()=>{
         validate();
         //some basic assertion follows
      });   
});
```

I really appreciate if some can guide me! I have been through the jest and babel documentation but those are of little to no help compared to stackoverflow!

Comment: `"type" : "module"` in `package.json`

Comment: ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope. This file is being treated as an ES module because it has .js extn,,
This is the error I see when I add "type" : "module"

Comment: just for reference here is my jest.config.js I am assuming the below js must be written in ES Module compatible ?

module.exports  = {
    transform: { 
   '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
}