# Jest encountered an unexpected token - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, config, settings, babel-jest

I couldn't get rid of this `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error no matter what I have tried and it got so frustrating.
Is there anybody out here solved this issue? I have read a million stackoverflow and github issue threads. No clear solutions.

### The error I get is

```
    Details:

    /Users/brandi/Documents/workspaces/admin-v1/adminWebpack/vueSourceCode/test/__tests__/test.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

### I have this setup:

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: [
        'js', 'json', 'vue'
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/vueSourceCode/$1',
        '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/vueSourceCode/$1'
    },
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
        '<rootDir>/build/',
        '<rootDir>/config/'
    ],
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
        '^[^.]+.vue$': 'vue-jest'
    },
    snapshotSerializers: [
        'jest-serializer-vue'
    ],
    testMatch: [
        '<rootDir>/vueSourceCode/(tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx))'
    ],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        '<rootDir>/node_modules/'
    ]
};
```

**babelrc**

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-2",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
      ]
    }
  },
  "test": [
    "jest"
  ]
}
```

Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest try using babel.config.js instead of .babelrc