# TS Jest "Cannot use import statement outside module". How to properly configure?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, ts-jest

I have a very simple react app (typescript) and I am trying to configure and run component tests using jest and @testing-library.

When I try to render() one of the components jest throws an error saying that it cannot use import statement outside a module.

The particular problem comes from this line

```
C:\github\DeviceCatalogue.UI\node_modules\axios\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
```

[image]

Before posting here I've read multiple articles and stackoverflow posts, but none of the solutions work for me. Like for example this one: [How to resolve "Cannot use import statement outside a module" in jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-in-jest)

Here are some of the important files. Please let me know if this is enough as information:

1. jest.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/setupTests.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)?$': ['ts-jest']
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
};
```

2. package.json

```js
{
  "name": "device-catalogue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.9",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.19.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.64",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.5.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.8",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "t": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.2.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.2.2",
    "msw": "^0.47.4",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3"
  }
}
```

3. babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
};
```

4. tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

5. setupTests.ts

```js
// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import mswServer from './__mocks__/server';

beforeAll(() => mswServer.listen());

afterEach(() => mswServer.resetHandlers());

afterAll(() => mswServer.close());
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find and fix the problem.
I had to also transform the axios package, because by default it is being ignored by ts-jest transforms.

In jest.config.js I added this:

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!axios)'],
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this issue, and I am looking for all the threads that I read to update with what worked for me.

My app is built with React Native and Typescript. I'm testing with React Native Testing Library and Jest.

Adding these lines to my `tsconfig.json` worked for a React Native App with TypeScript:

```
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

For extra information, I'll leave my other config files below:

//tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "paths": {
      "test-utils": ["./utils/test-utils"]
    },
    "types": ["@testing-library/jest-native", "jest", "node"]
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

//jest.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from "@jest/types"

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  preset: "jest-expo",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  verbose: true,
  setupFiles: ["./jestSetupFile.js"],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '^.+\\.js?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
   },
   transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native|@react-navigation)",
    
  ]
}
export default config
```

//babel.config.cjs

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      '@babel/preset-react',
      {runtime: "automatic"}
    ],
    [
      '@babel/preset-flow'
    ],
    [
      '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ],
    [
      'babel-preset-expo',
    ],
  ],
  plugins: ['expo-router/babel']
};
```