# Detox: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs, es6-modules, detox

I'm trying to run detox typescript tests in my react-native app. When an import is encountered in the test, the following error is thrown:

```js
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module


Details:

      import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
      2 | import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
    > 3 | import VersionNumber from 'react-native-version-number';
          ^^^^^^
```

All this comes from a class I import inside the test file, which in turn imports other things that it needs.

If the test files have no imports, they work just fine.

For the past few hours I have been trying to fix this, by adjusting my `jest.config.js` file but to no avail, I don't understand how this works. The solution from what I understood by googling is to use Babel to transpile the code and the imports from ES6 to commonJS, before detox/jest use them. But there are so many options in the config and the setup is not simple, I don't understand how to do it.

Below are my config files:

`jest.config.js`

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest');

const { compilerOptions } = require('../tsconfig.json');

/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
module.exports = {
  rootDir: '..',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/e2e/**/*.test.ts'],
  testTimeout: 120000,
  maxWorkers: 1,
  globalSetup: 'detox/runners/jest/globalSetup',
  globalTeardown: 'detox/runners/jest/globalTeardown',
  reporters: ['detox/runners/jest/reporter'],
  testEnvironment: 'detox/runners/jest/testEnvironment',
  verbose: true,
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths, { prefix: '<rootDir>/' }),
};
```

`babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json'],
        alias: {
          '@app': './src',
          '@assets': './assets',
        },
      },
    ],
    ['module:react-native-dotenv', { envName: 'DOTENV', moduleName: '@env' }],
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['transform-remove-console'],
    },
  },
};
```

`.detoxrc.js` (relevant code only)

```js
/** @type {Detox.DetoxConfig} */
module.exports = {
  testRunner: {
    args: {
      $0: 'jest',
      config: 'e2e/jest.config.js',
    },
    jest: {
      setupTimeout: 120000,
    },
  },
  apps: {...},
  devices: {...},
  configurations: {...},
};
```

What I read and tried:

- [How to resolve "Cannot use import statement outside a module" from Jest when running tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613492/how-to-resolve-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-from-jest-when-run)
- https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Cannot+use+import+statement+outside+a+module
- https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

I would really appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and have also spent hours trying to figure it out, to no avail. Hopefully someone here can help us out! (Did you ever get it to work?)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't